# autoEl width and height property in ExtJS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building a web app using ExtJS4 and I want to put a href on an image.

I have an image defined as such:

```
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                x: 87,
                y: 180,
                autoEl: {
                    tag: 'a',
                    href: 'resources/promoStubs/eventTalkPromo.jpg',
                    target: '_blank',
                    x: 87,
                    y: 180,
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                    length: 30,
                    
                },
                height: 30,
                itemId: 'paw1',
                width: 30,
                src: 'resources/graphics/pawpromo.png'
            },
```

I got the idea from [this JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hnPbm/3/)

However, what happens is that the image is very large and the `width` and `height` properties are not applied at all to the image. Any ideas on how to specify width and height in an image with an autoEl property?

Answer (score 0):

Please add an ***imgCls*** attribute to your xtype, like shown below and  write a css class for the same.
Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnPbm/14/)

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        src: 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/512/social_google_box.png',

        imgCls:'yourCSScls',


        //defines the element that wraps around the image
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'a',
            href: 'http://www.google.com',
            target: '_blank'

                   //add any other attributes to the 'a' tag as needed
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you.